# Using owin middlelayer

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am new to using the OWIN interface.
I have a few questions regarding implementing it.

1. How do I create an authorization middle layer using OWIN
   implementation
2. How do I handle anonymous requests through the middle layer
3. Where in the pipeline should i place the authorization and
   authentication for accessing our webapi's

Experts please have mercy and kindly explain with examples.

Comment: It is more about the design how to process the anonymous requests. How to place authorization filter and how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what helped me get OWIN working within a Web API project:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

That link should answer #1. For #2, allowing anonymous requests is as simple as adding the [AllowAnonymous] attribute to a controller.

For #3, if you set OWIN up correctly, all authentication takes place before any of your controller code gets hit. In a way, it's all taken care of by .Net Here's a link to a more in-depth sample:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/869223/ASP-NET-Web-Api-Create-a-Self-Hosted-OWIN-Based-We